# I need a function that it receive a function by parameter that can be called inside

Tags: java

I want to do a function for execute any function received by parameter in intervals.
To explain myself better, I will give you an example.

I want to use this function for make calls to a rest client but, instead of do the call with a list with 10 elements, I want to can do 5 calls with 2 elements.

My problem is I don't want have to manage loops and intervals in all methods that I want call in intervals, I would like do something like this: Util.executeInIntervals (2 (interval), this.restClient.doPost(fullList) ); This method should do calls to this restClient in intervals as indicated below.

I have been able to this example class but the result isn't the correct:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionAsParameter {
  
  public static <T> void executeInIntervals(List<T> list, int interval, Function function) {
    // It's defined the num of interval
    final int INTERVAL = interval;

    int cont = 0;
    while(list.size() - cont > INTERVAL) {
      function.apply(list.subList(cont,cont + INTERVAL).toString());
      cont = cont + INTERVAL;
    }
    // The rest are processed
    function.apply(list.subList(cont,list.size()));
  }
}
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    
    FunctionAsParameter.executeInIntervals(list, 2, value -> {
      // Here it would be the call to rest client with the sublist, not the full list 
      System.out.println(list);
      // This I would like remove but java indicates that the function can't be void
      return "";
    });
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Correct result would be:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: It seems your question has multiple not-so-clear requirements. You want a higher-order function to accept another function that should make HTTP calls. Why? Instead of telling us what you want, start by explaining the problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: Indeed, your problem can be easily done using a for loop without having a callback and an interval and all that. So please indicate if having a callback is a requirement, and if so why?

Comment: In the lambda (the part in `{}` from `value -> {}`) you currently print out the complete list from the `main()` method (`System.out.println(list);`). You should start with printing out the parameter that `executeInIntervals()` passes (`System.out.println(value);`)

Comment: My problem is I don't want have to manage loops and intervals in all methods that I want call in intervals, I would like do something like this:

Util.executeInIntervals (2 (interval), this.restClient.doPost(fullList) );

This method should do calls to this restClient in intervals as indicated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback ignores the parameter you pass into it and it is also unclear what the parameter should be (you call it once with a `String` and once with a `List<T>`).

You could try to fix your code like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionAsParameter {
  
  public static <T> void executeInIntervals(List<T> list, int interval, Function<List<T>, String> function) {
    // It's defined the num of interval
    final int INTERVAL = interval;

    int cont = 0;
    while (list.size() - cont > INTERVAL) {
      function.apply(list.subList(cont, cont + INTERVAL));
      cont = cont + INTERVAL;
    }
    // The rest are processed
    function.apply(list.subList(cont, list.size()));
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    
    FunctionAsParameter.executeInIntervals(list, 2, value -> {
      System.out.println(value);
      return "";
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to remove that `return "";` (because you don't use the return value of that function anyway) then `Function` is the wrong interface - you should use a `Consumer`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ConsumerAsParameter {

    public static <T> void executeInIntervals(List<T> list, int interval, Consumer<List<T>> consumer) {
        // It's defined the num of interval
        final int INTERVAL = interval;

        int cont = 0;
        while (list.size() - cont > INTERVAL) {
            consumer.accept(list.subList(cont, cont + INTERVAL));
            cont = cont + INTERVAL;
        }
        // The rest are processed
        consumer.accept(list.subList(cont, list.size()));
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

        ConsumerAsParameter.executeInIntervals(list, 2, value -> {
            System.out.println(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that in this simple example you could replace the `executeInIntervals()` call even further:

```
ConsumerAsParameter.executeInIntervals(list, 2, System.out::println);
```

For the example that you mention in a comment, the code could look like this:

```
ConsumerAsParameter.executeInIntervals(fullList, 2, this.restClient::doPost));
```